# Java Functional to Recursive Function Problem

Tags: java, recursion, functional-programming

I need help to convert this functional java  function into a recursive one

```
public static Map<Integer,List<String>> funcional(List<List<String>> listas) {
        return listas.stream()
        .flatMap(lista -> lista.stream())
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(String::length));
    }
```

Tried with this:

```
public static Map<Integer,List<String>> recursiva(List<List<String>> listas){
        return recursivaAux(listas, 0, 0, new HashMap<>(), new ArrayList<>());
    }
    
    private static Map<Integer,List<String>> recursivaAux(List<List<String>> listas, Integer i, Integer ii, 
                                                            Map<Integer,List<String>> res, List<String> ls){
        if(i<listas.size()) {
            if(ii<listas.get(i).size()) {
                Integer size = listas.get(i).get(ii).length();
                String word = listas.get(i).get(ii);
                if(res.containsKey(size)) {
                    ls = res.get(size);
                    ls.add(word);
                    res.put(size, ls);
                }else {
                    ls.add(word);
                    res.put(size, ls);
                }
                recursivaAux(listas, i, ii+1, res, new ArrayList<>());
            }
            recursivaAux(listas, i+1, 0, res, new ArrayList<>());
        }
        return res;
    }
```

But it gives me the map with repeated string values for each key.

Functional gives first line result (correct one)
but Recursive one gives the second line which repeated
many values as you see
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2VW2z.png)

Comment: I can't see exactly what's wrong, but if I were doing this, I'd have two recursive functions, one to iterate through `listas`, the second to iterate through each `List<String>` value. You can avoid a lot of complexity that way.

Comment: Also you're creating a lot of `ArrayList<String>` objects and passing them in as parameters, but they're only used within the function, and often not even used if one already exists. So you can remove that parameter, and only allocate a new `ArrayList<String>` if `res.containsKey(size)` is false.

Comment: The reason why you want it to be recursive would be nice to know. What you try to achieve is not a "natural fit" for a recursive algorithm. It's not going to be efficient or mintainable.

Comment: To make your code more of an [mre] please include hard-coded test data and the expected output.